# Django "Column Is Not Unique" with get_or_create()

Tags: database, django

Using Django 1.6, I am getting '`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column thread_id is not unique`'. Indeed, there exists a object/record #3477. But what I don't understand is that I am using get_or_create()...so if the record is there it shouldn't be trying to add it. Not sure what to do about this and why it is doing this.

```
def database_udpate(thread_batch):
    sanitized_threads = [] 
    query_set = ThreadVault.objects.all()
    for thread in thread_batch:
        print thread
        obj, created = query_set.get_or_create(
                thread_id=thread["thread_id"],
                author_username=thread["author_username"],
                latest_post_date=thread["latest_post_date"],
                url=thread["url"],
                reply_count=thread["reply_count"],
                forum_id=thread["forum_id"],
                author_name=thread["author_name"],
                subject=thread["subject"],
                defaults={ 'assigned_irc_name' :
                    None }) 
        sanitized_threads.append(obj)
    unanswered_threads_table(sanitized_threads)


  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 450, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column thread_id is not unique
```

**UPDATE/EDIT**:

models.py:

```
class ThreadVault(models.Model):
    thread_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length="200")
    author_username = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    forum_id = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length="200")
    reply_count = models.CharField(max_length=("3"))
    latest_post_date = models.CharField(max_length=("50"))
    assigned_irc_name = models.ForeignKey(Employee, 
            null=True, blank=True)

    objects = models.Manager()
    #unassigned_threads = UnassignedThread()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.thread_id)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_unaswered_threads.py", line 92, in <module>
    get_unanswered_threads()
  File "get_unaswered_threads.py", line 53, in get_unanswered_threads
    database_udpate(thread_batch)
  File "get_unaswered_threads.py", line 73, in database_udpate
    None })
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 388, in get_or_create
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get_or_create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1511, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 899, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 450, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column thread_id is not unique
```

Comment: Can you show us your `ThreadVault` class? Maybe `thread_id` is unique in your db and not on your model? Also, why call `get_or_create` on the query set instead of the plain model class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, some of those fields have changed since the last save to the database, otherwise you wouldn't need to update the record. `get_or_create` will query to match *all* of the attributes, which is why it isn't really a very useful function. You could move the non-matching ones to `defaults`, but the problem now is that they won't be updated if the record *does* exist.

Instead, it's probably better to use get within a try/except and update where necessary:

```
try:
    thread_vault = ThreadVault.objects.get(id=thread['thread_id']
except ThreadVault.DoesNotExist:
    thread_vault = ThreadVault()
thread_vault.author_username=thread["author_username"]
# etc.
```

(It seems that in the upcoming version 1.7 there will be an `update_or_create` method which does exactly this, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create).

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) has this to say:

> The get_or_create() method has similar error behavior to create() when
>   you’re using manually specified primary keys. If an object needs to be
>   created and the key already exists in the database, an IntegrityError
>   will be raised.

I could be off, but at a guess: since `thread_id` matches, all the other columns should match as well (and match exactly). Since that doesn't happen, an IntegrityError is raised.
Perhaps `thread_id` is a unique column?